# Get result from aggs in script ElasticSearch/Painless

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I'm new in ElasticSearch world. I've been trying write simple request and I need to get aggs result in my script to make simple condition. Is it possible to do it in this way?
The condition below is only for example.

```
GET _search
{
  "aggs" : {
      "sum_field" : { "sum" : { "field" : "someField" } }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "script_name": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
             // get there aggs result (sum_field)
              if(sum_field > 5){
                  return sum_field
              }
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is to execute [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) over *multiple indexes* having the *same field name*

Now with multiple indexes, you'll have to check if that particular field *exists in that indexes or not* AND if the field is of the **same datatype**.

### Indexes

I've created three indexes, having a single field called `num`.

```
index_1
     - num: long

index_2
     - num: long

index_3
     - num: text
          : fielddata: true
```

Also notice how if the field is of type `text`, then I've set its property `fielddata:true`. But if you do not set it, then the below query would give you aggregation result as well as an error saying you cannot retrieve the value of type `text` as its an analyzed string and you can only use `doc` for fields which are `non_analyzed`.

### Sample Query:

```
POST /_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "exists":{  
                  "field":"num"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "myaggs":{  
         "sum":{  
            "script":{  
               "source":"if(doc['num'].value instanceof long) return doc['num'].value;"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Query if you cannot set `fielddata:true`

In that case, you need to explicitly mention the indexes on which you'd want to aggregate.

```
POST /_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "exists":{  
                  "field":"num"
               }
            },
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "_index":[  
                     "index_1",
                     "index_2"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "myaggs":{  
         "sum":{  
            "script":{  
               "source":"if(doc['num'].value instanceof long) return doc['num'].value;"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your suggest didn't solve my problem at all. But maybe you could give me advice how to use script for whole hits list? Cuz when I have something like in below code it executes only for current index, not for whole list. I would like to use this script to sum some field (I know it's possible by "aggs sum" as u wrote above).

`GET _search
{
  "query": { 
   "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "source": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        
          return params._source
        """
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: hey @XtrEmE if I understand it correctly, what you want is, say you have a field `someField` which is present in **multiple indexes**, what you want is a script that can perform `sum` on its values over **all indices**? It'd be great if you can just update the question with a sample output and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: I want to write a script which will execute not only for current index but for whole array. 
Typically it could be like below, but this code is nested for index. I need to have access one step higher.

`"source": """
          int sum = 0;
          
          for(int i = 0; i < hits.lenght; i++){
            sum += hits[i].fieldValue;  
          }
          
          return sum;
        """`

Comment: hey @XtrEmE, yes I've got it. You'd want to do aggregation on a particular field if it is present in all the indexes. Not sure if Elastic supports aggregation results on index levels but let me try and update you on it.

Comment: @XtrEmE could you please check the answer now? I've updated it with what you are looking for. Let me know if that helps!